# Jenkins unable to execute .sh script on ubuntu permission denied?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, jenkins, sh

Currently attempting to execute a shell script via Jenkins using a pipeline job but receiving the following error:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Warehouse_Tests/src/test/java/runners/sql.sh: Permission denied
```

I have configured:

```
visudo -f /etc/sudoers
```

to contain:

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
jenkins ALL= NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The script probably does not have executable permissions.

Comment: thanks for the reply @Matt Schuchard do you know how I would add permissions to the script?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved by executing: `sh chmod +x` against the .sh script prior to triggering the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

change the permission of files to **jenkins:jenkins & 755 .**

in the build only you can mentioned it .

also try to run with sudo

```
sudo sh /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Warehouse_Tests/src/test/java/runners/sql.sh
```

suggestion - use Jenkins environment variable rather giving an actual path of your script.

Comment: how would I pass a jenkins environment variable into an shell script?

Comment: BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME=#18
BUILD_ID=18
BUILD_NUMBER=18
JENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins
WORKSPACE=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/list_environment_variables
above are the few example of jenkins variable . you can test it with echo $WORKSPACE in linux .